# How to overcome "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str" in for pa in data["result"]

Tags: python

I face the following problem, for pa in data["result"] the following error is displayed "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str". Could you suggest me which kind of manipulation should I make to the code for letting it running without displaying the error?

```
with open("data/indicePA/indicePA.tsv", 'w') as f_indice_pa , open("data/indicePA/otherPA.tsv", 'w') as f_other:
        writer_indice_pa = csv.writer(f_indice_pa, delimiter ='\t')
        writer_other_pa = csv.writer(f_other, delimiter ='\t')

        count = 0
        res = ["cf", "cod_amm", "regione", "provincia", "comune", "indirizzo", "tipologia_istat", "tipologia_amm"]
        writer_indice_pa.writerow(res)
        writer_other_pa.writerow(["cf"])

        for pa in data["result"]:
            esito = pa["esitoUltimoTentativoAccessoUrl"]
            if esito == "successo":
                cf = pa["codiceFiscale"]

                if cf in cf_set_amm:
                    try:
                        cod_amm = df_amm.loc[df_amm['Cf'] == cf].iloc[0]['cod_amm']
                        take0 = df_amm.loc[df_amm['cod_amm'] == cod_amm].iloc[0]
                        regione = take0['Regione'].replace("\t", "")
                        provincia = str(take0['Provincia']).replace("\t", "")
                        comune = take0['Comune'].replace("\t", "")
                        indirizzo = take0['Indirizzo'].replace("\t", "")
                        tipologia_istat = take0['tipologia_istat'].replace("\t", "")
                        tipologia_amm = take0['tipologia_amm'].replace("\t", "")

                        res = [cf, cod_amm, regione, provincia, comune, indirizzo, tipologia_istat, tipologia_amm]
                        writer_indice_pa.writerow(res)
                    except: # catch *all* exceptions
                        print("CF in df_amm",cf)
                elif cf in cf_set_serv_fatt:
                    try:
                        cod_amm = df_serv_fatt.loc[df_serv_fatt['Cf'] == cf].iloc[0]['cod_amm']
                        take0 = df_amm.loc[df_amm['cod_amm'] == cod_amm].iloc[0]
                        regione = take0['Regione'].replace("\t", "")
                        provincia = str(take0['Provincia']).replace("\t", "")
                        comune = take0['Comune'].replace("\t", "")
                        indirizzo = take0['Indirizzo'].replace("\t", "")
                        tipologia_istat = take0['tipologia_istat'].replace("\t", "")
                        tipologia_amm = take0["tipologia_amm"].replace("\t", "")
                        res = [cf, cod_amm, regione, provincia, comune, indirizzo, tipologia_istat, tipologia_amm]
                        writer_indice_pa.writerow(res)
                    except: # catch *all* exceptions
                        #e = sys.exc_info()[0]
                        print("CF in df_serv_fatt",cf)
                else:
                    #print(cf, " is not present")
                    count = count + 1
                    writer_other_pa.writerow([cf])
                    #if(count % 100 == 0):
                        #print(cf)

        print("Totale cf non presenti in IndicePA: ", count)
        f_indice_pa.flush()   
        f_other.flush()

    I expect to obtain the following statement "Totale cf non presenti in IndicePA:  1148", because this code has been already run. But I face this problem. How to overcome it? Is there any manipulation that I can make to this original code?
```

Thanks for your help in advance. 
It is possible to find a wider explanation of the code at the following link: [link resource](https://github.com/fabiana001/anacAnalysis/blob/master/notebooks/1_Analisi_IndicePA_OpenConsip.ipynb)

Comment: What type of object is `data`? I don't see it defined in your code snippet. It appears to be a list, in which case you would need to index into it with an integer (`data[0]`), but you appear to be trying to index into it as though it's a dictionary or dataframe (`data["result"]`)

Comment: data = json.load(open(file_lista_anac_pa))

Comment: where file_lista_anac_pa is a json file

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation for the json module you are using to parse that json file.

[image: Found at https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html Section 18.2.2]

This chart can be found at https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html Section 18.2.2

It seems like your json object is getting parsed as a list. According to that chart the object must be an array. Like such...

```
[
    { 
        "result" : { someObject }
    }
]
```

A simple fix might be editing the json so it is parsed correctly to a dict. For example...

```
{
    "result": {
          someObjectStuff
    }
}
```

Another fix could be accessing the first element in the list. If your json looks like the following

```
[
    { 
        "result" : { someObject }
    }
]
```

Then changing the code to be

```
for pa in data[0]["result"]:
```

Might also fix the problem.

Comment: Thank you. 
It has been enough to delete ["result"] from data.